# XML processing instructions

Tags: java, xml

The following code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("out.xml"));
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to statements element

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {

            t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StreamResult("result.txt"));
        }
    }
}
```

produces some txt, and on the first line of it there are processing instructions (`<?xml version="1.0">`). Where do they come from and how to get rid of them? And how to manipulate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the creation of the xml declaration by setting the [output properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on the transformer:

```
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

If you want to generate text files from the xml then you probably want to specify an XSLT source in the `TransformerFactory.newInstance` call and set the output properties in that XSLT.

Comment: WRONG-WRONG. In theory It should work, BUT it doesn't. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598345/omitting-xml-declaration-when-invoking-transformer-with-staxresult) question. This is the problem I have

Comment: That question seems to be about using a `StaxResult` and even says that the xml decl is omitted when using a `StreamResult`. But I did not actually run the code to verify this.

Comment: yes, you are right. You see, initially my task was to figure out how to get rid of xml declaration generally, and you answered this. But in my code i am using stax result, so, while it worked with the demo, it didn't with my code. It works with StreamResult indeed

Comment: but it was a different problem, so, guess this was answered

Answer (score 0):

The line `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is an xml declaration. According to the [W3C XML Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd)

> XML documents SHOULD begin with an XML declaration which specifies the version of XML being used.

it is supposed to be there (albeit not mandatory).

Btw. in a strict technical sense it is not a processing instruction.

Edit: the encoding can be changed with:

```
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i mean HOW does it appear in my txt? What if i want it to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"` , but instead `<?xml version="1.0"?>` appears because "it is supposed to be there"

Comment: thank you . If you know how to solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731363/xml-transform-and-linebreak-characters/21731529?noredirect=1#21731529), it would be supercool as well

Comment: WRONG-WRONG. In theory It should work, BUT it doesn't. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598345/omitting-xml-declaration-when-invoking-transformer-with-staxresult) question. This is the problem I have